# Undefined method 'admin' for Devise::FailureApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise setup on a mountable engine. However, I'm getting this really weird bug. When I add `before_action :authenticate_admin_user` I get this error:

```
undefined method `admin' for #<Devise::FailureApp:0x00007f95877219f0>
```

and the piece of code at which the error is showing up at is this:

```
context = send(router_name)
```

I know that `router_name` is not nil, because I have the `better_errors` gem and I was able to check to see if `router_name` is nil, and it's not, it's returning 'admin'.

In my devise initializer, I have the following:

```
config.router_name = :admin
config.parent_controller = 'Admin::ApplicationController'
```